# Display size doesn't match windows resolution

Tags: windows, windows-10, display

The resolution of the Windows instance on my HP Envy x360 laptop suddenly no longer matches the actual resolution of the in-built screen.
[image: A picture for clarity]
My display drivers and Windows are all fully up to date.
Hard resets have no effect at all.
Nothing in the display settings seems to indicate that anything is wrong.
This leads me to believe this is a problem with my display driver (Intel HD Graphics).
Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: HP has made different models of the Envy x360 with or without a dedicated graphics card. What model is yours?

Comment: @spike_66 HP ENVY 15-u011dx x360 Convertible PC (ENERGY STAR)

Comment: Download the latest [drivers](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/27780/Intel-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-15-40-?product=81497) (win64_15.40.38.4963.zip) for Intel HD Graphics 4400. Extract the files and double click on igxpin.exe to install

Comment: I already installed the latest driver: it did not change anything

Comment: Then try to install the [graphics driver](https://support.hp.com/si-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-envy-15-u000-x360-convertible-pc/6944194/model/7242141) that HP provides for this model

Comment: I already did that too :(